# Fetch Data from an API and save in an sqlite database Flutter Dart Android

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

I have a insertUser method that works fine when i click a button or trigger it another way. I have a fetchUser method that fetches users data from an API. I call the fetch method in initState to fetch the data as soon as the app launches and that is also working fine. In my fetchUser method, i loop through the data collected, pass it to a user object and save in a database. I am able to create user objects for each user but cant save it in the database. Here is my code.

```
 Future<List<User>> fetchUser() async {
    final response =
    await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      parsed.forEach((entry) {
        String name = entry["name"];
        String username = entry["username"];
        String passcode = entry["username"];
        print("id: $name, username: $username, passcode: $passcode");

        var newUser = User(
          name: name,
          username: username,
          passcode: name,
        );

        print(newUser.passcode);
        UserDatabase.instance.insertUser(user);  //this is not working

      });

      return parsed.map<User>((json) => User.fromMapp(json)).toList();

      // return parsed.map<User>((json) => User.fromMap(json)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load users');
    }
  }
```

The insert method

```
  insertUser(User user) async{
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return  await db.insert(_table_field_agents, user.toUserMap(),conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.ignore
    );
  }
```

I call `fetchUser` in `initState`, everything works alright except saving the data to the database.

Comment: uh, okay, where to start... you should really make this two methods, one to fetch data, one to write it to your database. Then you should crank your linter to maximum and fix all the issues that pop up, especially around Futures. With the existing problems, there is no telling where *exactly* it might go wrong. And the fact that you claim everything works except one thing is something I would doubt, given that you have not posted the method in question. For all we know, it might be a bug in that method or your UI.

Comment: And what is with the `instance` fields? Do you really have a double singleton? There are better ways.

Comment: @nvoigt the fetch works, i am able to print out what i am getting from request. I have a button that takes a hard coded User object and write the data to the sqllite database. in the fetch where i create a User object before writing the data to the database also works(I am able to create a user. The problem is in my fetch method, the user object doesnt write to the database.

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No i don't get an error.